# How to use select query inside the select column name by iterating column row values using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
select column_one, column_two, column_three 
from main_tbl_name
```

Output:

```
column_one  column_two
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data1       SBANAR SBARTO SCBADP SCCHBA SCHPIT SCTHAB SDPCLV SDPRPN SDPSEC SERIE
data2       SRALEN SRETIN SRUNLI SSAPEL SSATAR SSCMAR SSDECA
data3       DRAP14 E05A E1 ECOMOD ENJO01 ENPC01 ESPHSA ESS
```

I have another query:

```
select column_one, column_two, column_three 
from another_tbl_name 
where column_four in (main_tbl_name.column_two)
```

I need to split up the values of `main_tbl_name.column_two` into for example like ('SBANAR','SBARTO','SCBADP','SCCHBA','SCHPIT','SCTHAB','SDPCLV','SDPRPN','SDPSEC','SERIE')

In the above second query if some of the values exist, append each iterated value in `main_tbl_name.column_three`

So my final output should be

```
column_one  column_two                                                                  column_three
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data1       SBANAR SBARTO SCBADP SCCHBA SCHPIT SCTHAB SDPCLV SDPRPN SDPSEC SERIE        SBANAR SBARTO SCCHBA SDPCLV SDPSEC
data2       SRALEN SRETIN SRUNLI SSAPEL SSATAR SSCMAR SSDECA                            SRALEN SSCMAR SSDECA
data3       DRAP14 E05A E1 ECOMOD ENJO01 ENPC01 ESPHSA ESS                              DRAP14 E05A ESPHSA ESS
```

Comment: Poor design. Storing data as blank separated values will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: but i don't have any other option without splitting and checking in another tables

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with data similiar to yours:

```
with 

-- sample data
  main_tbl_name ( column_one,  column_two) as (
    select 'data1', 'SBANAR SBARTO SCBADP SCCHBA SCHPIT SCTHAB SDPCLV SDPRPN SDPSEC SERIE' 
      from dual union all
    select 'data2', 'SRALEN SRETIN SRUNLI SSAPEL SSATAR SSCMAR SSDECA' 
      from dual union all
    select 'data3', 'DRAP14 E05A E1 ECOMOD ENJO01 ENPC01 ESPHSA ESS' from dual ),
  another_tbl_name(column_four) as (
    select 'SDPSEC SBANAR SBARTO SCCHBA SDPCLV' from dual union all
    select 'DRAP14 E05A ESPHSA ESS' from dual), 
  -- end of sample data

  t1 as (select column_one c1, column_two c2, '"'||replace(column_two, ' ', '", "')||'"' cx 
           from main_tbl_name),
  t2 as (select '"'||replace(column_four, ' ', '", "')||'"' cx 
           from another_tbl_name)
select c1, c2, listagg(b.cs, ' ') within group (order by b.cs) c3
  from (select c1, c2, trim(column_value) cs from t1, xmltable(cx)) a
  left join (select trim(column_value) cs from t2, xmltable(cx)) b on a.cs = b.cs
  group by c1, c2
```

... which results:

```
C1    C2                                                                   C3
----- -------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------
data1 SBANAR SBARTO SCBADP SCCHBA SCHPIT SCTHAB SDPCLV SDPRPN SDPSEC SERIE SBANAR SBARTO SCCHBA SDPCLV SDPSEC
data2 SRALEN SRETIN SRUNLI SSAPEL SSATAR SSCMAR SSDECA
data3 DRAP14 E05A E1 ECOMOD ENJO01 ENPC01 ESPHSA ESS                       DRAP14 E05A ESPHSA ESS
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e181c7e376dcd590bb704ae3dbc82872)</sup>**

This solution is based on `xmltable`, left join and `listagg()`. I assumed that single space is the separator. If `another_table` contains data not in the form of list then you can even simplify this query.

Basically you have to split *list* columns then make join. There are also other ways to do this like hierarchical queries, PLSQL functions, already posted on SO. Use whatever method which suits you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to:

- Convert the main_tbl_name.column_two to rows
- For each of these generated rows, link to one of the existing table rows
  ?

If so, you can do something like below:

```sql
WITH DATA AS
     ( SELECT 44 AS COLUMN_ONE  ,'WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 <!-- language: lang-sql --> WORD4 WORD5 WORD6' COLUMN_TWO FROM DUAL     )
SELECT COLUMN_ONE  ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN_TWO, <!-- language: lang-sql --> '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)) COLUMN_TWO
FROM DATA
CONNECT BY INSTR(COLUMN_TWO, ' ', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0;

COLUMN_ONE  COLUMN_TWO
44          WORD1
44          WORD2
44          WORD3
44          WORD4
44          WORD5
44          WORD6
```

Cheers!!!
Dhilen